# Why am I obtaing this error message trying to attach a method to a button click? No overload for btnSalvaNota_Click match delegate 'EventHandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am pretty new in **C#** and **.NET** and I am finding some difficulties trying to change a button into a SharePoint 2013 WebPart.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
internal class TabAnnotazioni
{
    internal static void CreaTabAnnotazioni(FormProtocolloWebPart.FormProtocolloWebPartUserControl fp, Panel tabPanel, SPListItem item, SPControlMode controlMode, Utente user, Ruolo ruoloUtente, DBConnection dbConfig)
    {
            .......................................................
            .......................................................
            .......................................................

            ImageButton printButton = new ImageButton();
            printButton.ToolTip = "Aggiungi nota";
            printButton.Click += fp.btnSalvaNota_Click;
            printButton.ID = "btnNote";
            printButton.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Ribbon/nota.png";
            Label text = new Label();
            text.Text = "Aggiungi nota";
            text.Width = 100;
    }
}
```

I am trying to replace this **ImageButton** with a simple **Button** object. So I have done something like this:

```
Button printButton = new Button();
printButton.Text = "Aggiungi nota";
printButton.Click += fp.btnSalvaNota_Click;
printButton.CssClass = "shiny-blue";
printButton.ID = "btnNote";
```

The problem is on this line:

```
printButton.Click += fp.btnSalvaNota_Click;
```

Visual Studio highlights the following error message: **No overload for btnSalvaNota_Click match delegate 'EventHandler'**

Into my **FormProtocolloWebPart.FormProtocolloWebPartUserControl** class I have this method:

```
internal void btnSalvaNota_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ....................................................................
    ....................................................................
    ....................................................................
}
```

Why am I finding this error? What is wrong? How can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `internal void btnSalvaNota_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)`

to

`internal void btnSalvaNota_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

The type of the `e` is not compatible with a standard button.